# Is it possible to allow user to login into to the site based on IP address?

Tags: php

I stored the users IP address when they are registered.After that if they access the site from another Ip address I need to ask some security questions based on the registration.So is it possible to track the IP address.Otherwise the IP will change frequently?.
p.s No need to bother about Proxies and IP spoofing.

Comment: DO NOT AUTHENTICATE BASED ON IP ADDRESSES

Comment: Why would you ever want to authenticate this way?  What's wrong with using a cookie or sessions to remember a user the next time they come to your site?

Comment: I don't interpret this question as Authenticating based on IP.  My bank does something similar to what he's asking for.  Occasionally I'll access the bank site from a different computer, and the website will ask me additional security questions on top of my usually username/password.  Pretty sure that's what he's asking for.

Comment: @AI W yes exactly I need like that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` returns the IP address. You know that, since you stored it in the database. When they login, you simply try to match their IP with what you have in the database and popup the questions. I don't see where the problem is. Also, if you didn't, consider using `INET_NTOA` and `INET_ATON` ( http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html ) functions of MySQL.

Good luck annoying users!

Answer (score 2):

Unless you can guarantee that each user will have a consistent IP address (which you can't), why bother with this sort of "authentication"?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is no.  There's no way to track the IP address because a user could log on using a different computer, and the IP would be totally unrelated.

Answer (score 0):

In practice many different users from the public internet often use the same IP address via NAT or other IP sharing. DHCP is much more common than it was in days of yore, which means these IP addresses will be released and re-issued daily or at some other frequency. Mobile devices will change IP addresses frequently. So the stability and validity of an IP address varies by networking technology (cellular, cable, DSL, dial-up, etc).

This may be fine, based on your security policies. You should also look at nonces, forced logins, and other security mechanisms based on what your trying to accomplish. You may want to change the session id every N requests or hash the User Agent string with the IP address.